# How can i dissociate(remove) Ad account from my Facebook app using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to remove Ad account from my facebook application using facebook API. This process can be done from the app manager.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/applications/ allows you to read the list of apps associated with the ad account, but it says there that you can not update or delete via this endpoint.

Comment: Look-up in the other direction, from the app, is also possible, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/authorized_adaccounts/ - but again, says you can’t update or delete via that endpoint either.